# How do I enable color when running RSpec through RStakeout?

Tags: ruby, rspec

When using topfunky's [RStakeout](http://nubyonrails.com/articles/automation-with-rstakeout), the color in the result of the `spec` command is lost. This happens even when adding the `--color` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the environment variable `AUTOTEST` to true. Spec detects whether it is being run by a process and disables color if it is (to make the output easier to parse).

To set the environment variable in bash:

```
export AUTOTEST=true
```

or in fish:

```
set -x AUTOTEST true
```

(the -x exports the variable)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work with `--tty` in my .rspec file (use Rails 3.0.3 and rspec 2.3). I think it's `--autotest` for older version of 2.0. After an hour of searching, found it here - https://github.com/tomas-stefano/infinity_test